# Creating a Linux Socket seems to successfully bind but can't connect

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am currently learning C++ and I am creating a library that handles sockets for both Windows and Linux platforms. I've got the Windows version working fine but the Linux version seems to not work as expected.

Below is the code that I have to create a socket:

```
bool LinuxSocket::createSocket(int family, int socketType, int port, int bufferLength)
{
    BaseSocket::createsocket(port, bufferLength);
    this->serverSocket = socket(family, socketType, 0);
    if (this->serverSocket < 0)
    {
        bitsLibrary->writeToLog("Error opening socket", "LinuxSocket", "createSocket");
        return false;
    }
    bzero((char *)&this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = family;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_port = port;

    return true;
}
```

Below is the code for binding and starting the port to listen:

```
bool LinuxSocket::bindAndStartListening()
{
    stringstream logstream;
    int result = bind(this->serverSocket, (struct sockaddr * )&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (result < 0)
    {
        logstream << "Failed to bind socket. Error: " << strerror(result);
        this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "LinuxSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
        return false;
    }
    if (listen(this->serverSocket, this->socketPort) < 0)
    {
        this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog("Failed to start listening", "LinuxSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
        return false;
    }
    logstream << "Socket " << this->socketPort << " has been successfully bound";
    this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "LinuxSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
    return true;
}
```

Below is the code that accepts a client connection and returns the socket

```
int LinuxSocket::acceptClientAndReturnSocket(sockaddr_in *clientAddr)
{
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int clientSocket = accept(this->serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clilen);
    if (clientSocket < 0)
    {
        this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog("Unable to accept client socket");
        throw SocketException(strerror(clientSocket));
    }
    return clientSocket;
}
```

Below is how I am calling the methods

```
BitsLibrary bitsLibrary;
    StaticSettings staticSettings(&bitsLibrary, "tunnel.conf");

        LinuxSocket linuxSocket(&bitsLibrary);
        linuxSocket.createSocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 500, 20);
        linuxSocket.bindAndStartListening();

        sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        int clientSocket = linuxSocket.acceptClientAndReturnSocket(&clientAddr);
```

When I run the program no errors seem to be returned and I log out `Socket 500 has been successfully bound` so it seems like it works, however when trying to connect I get a connection refused.

I've then run `netstat -plna | grep 500` but this doesn't seem to return anything so it doesn't look like its actually binding the socket.

Comment: Use strace to verify all syscalls from your running process. No further help is possible without a [mcve].

Comment: Your error messages could print out `std::strerror(errno)` which can give you more detailed info.

Comment: 1) Why did you commented out `htons` when setting port? 2) Second argument in `listen` is not server port but backlog -- max number of allowed connections to be connected but not yet accepted.

Comment: Why is your (correct) htons call is being commented out? Because it didn't work with it? Well, it didn't work because you need root permissions to bind to any port below 1024.

Comment: I always forget about the strace command. I gave that a try and found the problem and it was because the IDE was not running as root

Comment: @gudok I thought that was the problem so I commented out but put it back now. Good to know about being below 1024 needing root didn't realise that

Comment: The `htons()` for the listening port is absolutely necessary. Also, your `bind()` code will only work when `family` is `AF_INET`. Try using `AF_INET6` instead and it will fail, because you need to use `sockaddr_in6`, which has a different memory layout than `sockaddr_in`. If you want to support multiple socket families, make sure `serv_addr` and `clientAddr` are both declared as `sockaddr_storage` and then type-cast them based on `family` when reading/writing their data fields.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RemyLebeau much appreciated